# Calculate the number of Equivalence relations for a set having 10 elements

Tags: algorithm

Given a set A with 10 elements, how to find the number of equivalence relations using nested if statements?

First of all, we can consider the set 12,3,...,10 for our purpose. It will do the same.

We can create an array of size 10×10 so that we get all 2-element combinations of 1,2,3,...,10. Note that the diagonal of the square matrix contains (a,a) for all a in {1,2,3...,10}. So, 2 to the power: upper half of the diagonal + the diagonal gives a count of the symmetric relations.

How to use if else conditions in programming to count the total number of equivalence relations? I am trying to use one of the upper or lower halves actually. This would reduce the time complexity of the program, but since I haven't completed it, I can't comment anymore though.

The worst case algorithm is perhaps to make a 2D array and check using if-else if both symmetric and transitive are satisfied or not. But that would be using O(n²). I'm trying to get a better algorithm.

Comment: Um... "Number of equivalence relations" - what is that supposed to mean? A typical student's problem would be to take *one specific given* equivalence relation and count the number of *equivalence classes* in a set. Is that what you are talking about? Or is it something else?

Comment: This is what I meant:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation

Comment: That's what I meant as well. And I still don't understand what you mean by "calculate the number of equivalence relations". The number of different equivalence relations for a set of `N` elements is exactly the number of ways to split that original set into subsets (the number of *partitions*). This number is called **Bell number** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number, the article explicitly mentions equivalence relations as well). The number is known to be `115975` for a set of `10` elements. Is that what you are looking for? But I don't see what "if statements" have to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bijection between equivalence relations on a set and partitions of the set. Counting the number of equivalence relation is the same as counting the number of partitions. The number of partitions of a set with `n` elements is the [Bell Number B_n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number).

There is a recurrence relation formula and no need for nested `if/then/else`. Please update your question to explicit what exactly you're trying to achieve and what are your constraints on the solution.

Comment: I know the partition concept/Bell numbers. But I would like to find the way of doing it using nested if/else.

Comment: @thomasdickens112 What do you mean by `doing it` ?

Comment: I mean the procedure to do it using nested if/else instead of using Bell numbers. Some hints would also help me.

Comment: @thomasdickens112 I voted to close this question as it is unclear and you're not doing any effort to clarify what you want.

Comment: I have written as much as I could in the question itself. I don't get what you mean. I have clearly explained my requirements. Regards